# "Iran Tourism" or "Iranian tourism"

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say this:

> I need to start making the necessary corrections on an article about Corporate Social Responsibility and Iran tourism. I was asked by the journal reviewers to do so before February 2nd.

A pal said Iranian tourism is better. Could someone explain it to me if there is a rule for using the name of countries in the adjective form?

Comment: *Iranian tourism* is correct, but it can be ambiguous, referring either to *tourism in Iran* or *tourism by Iranians*. I might suggest *tourism in Iran* or *tourism to Iran* as an alternative.

Comment: @choster Sure, if it's not clear from context which you mean. If you know who was writing the document and why, it might be obvious. Or it might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the "rule" is that if there's a standard adjectival form associated with a country name (or any other noun, for that matter), that form exists in order to be used. So use it.

There are various exceptions - for example, it's normally the [England cricket team](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22the%20England%20cricket%20team%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) because an [English cricket team](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22English%20cricket%20team%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) might be understood to mean *any* team whose players happen to be English. But unless I've missed out any major identifiable categories, I'll leave it to commenters to add more "counter-examples".

Answer (score 1):

We use an adjective when the word is modifying a noun. In this case, we are describing a type of tourism, namely, Iranian tourism, so we should use the adjective form of the name of the country.

A possible exception to this rule is that sometimes names of organizations and the like use the noun form of a place name when logically you might think that they should use the adjective form. For example -- okay, this may be a rather localized example, but it's the first that comes to mind -- the "Ohio Lottery Commission" is a commission that runs the state lottery in Ohio. Arguably it should be the "Ohioan Lottery Commission", but it's not. Or, the "Empire State Building", not the "Empire State's Building".